# Receiving a Key Error while merging three data frames with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, keyerror

I am trying to merge three data frames. Two of the df's use 'Country' and the third uses 'Country Name'. Edit* Images are below for SciEn and energy.

[ScimEn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZh27.png)

[energy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plUHo.png)

Can someone help me figure out where my Key Error is? I know that is has to do with 'Country' in the energy.csv file but I don't understand why there is an error.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
energy = pd.read_csv('Energy Indicators.csv')
GDP = pd.read_csv('world_bank_new.csv')
columns_to_keep = ['Country Name','Country Code','Indicator Name','Indicator Code',
                   '2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015']
GDP = GDP[columns_to_keep]
SciEm = pd.read_csv('scimagojr-3.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")



res = pd.merge(SciEm,energy,how='inner',on='Country').merge(GDP,how='inner',left_on='Country',right_on='Country Name').set_index('Country Name')
res.index.name = None

return pd.DataFrame(res,columns=dfcolumns).head(15)
```

Error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   1944             try:
-> 1945                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   1946             except KeyError:

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4154)()

pandas/index.pyx in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4018)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12368)()

pandas/hashtable.pyx in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12322)()

KeyError: 'Country'
```

Comment: Look at the output from the first merge. `res = pd.merge(SciEm,energy,how='inner',on='Country')` Is there a "Country" column there? Maybe it got transformed into "Country_x" and "Country_y" after the merge?

Comment: If I take out the second part of the merge and leave only the code you have, the code doesn't work. So I think Country in the energy file is doing something strange, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Getting closer- print out the column names of both: `print energy.columns` and `print SciEm.columns`. Sometimes column names have a trailing whitespace character, or different capitalization, or something else that's easy to miss.

Comment: For SciEm:



Index(['Rank', 'Country', 'Documents', 'Citable documents', 'Citations',
       'Self-citations', 'Citations per document', 'H index'],
      dtype='object')

For energy:



Index(['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per capita', '% Renewable'], dtype='object')

Comment: Trying getting rid of the last three lines of your code. Replace with: `res = pd.merge(SciEm,energy,how='inner',on='Country')`. Can you post the output to your question? The last two lines don't appear to be valid. I want to make sure the first merge is working, then we'll add the second.

Comment: Try using `SciEm.merge` and change your join to `how='left'` and as you are chaining another merge make that one `how='left'` as well and it should do the job.

Comment: The first merege with just SciEm and energy doesn't run. I tried doing what Boris mentioned and that also did not run. The issue is something with Country:

KeyError: 'Country'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-5b5a2919732c> in <module>()
     20 
     pd.merge(SciEm,energy,how='inner',on='Country').merge(GDP,how='inner',left_on='Country',right_on='Country Name').set_index('Country Name')

---> 15     res = pd.merge(SciEm,energy,how='inner',on='Country')

Comment: I wrote example in an answer and it should work just fine. Hope you are wrapping it in `def` because `return` will not work otherwise :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just put this into return, as I suggested in comment:

```
return SciEm.merge(GDP, how='left', left_on='Country', right_on='Country Name').merge(energy, how='left', left_on='Country', right_on='Country').drop('Country Name', axis=1).set_index('Country').head(15)
```

Comment: Could it be that you haven't read your files in a proper manner? Can you send a print-screen of the files you are merging?

Comment: Added images to the original.

Comment: Now that you figured the issue, did my code work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the original .csv file. I accidentally saved it as a .txt.

The strange thing, though, was that the image of the file didn't look like a .txt. It still looked like a .csv.